# MATLAB GUI Program Chrashes on .fig Load

Tags: matlab, user-interface, figure

I made some updates to my GUI .fig file - renaming everything (someone else created the initial GUI), moving things around, and adding a couple objects. I don't think I tried running the program/GUI without generating an error, but the last time I tried running it, I got a crash (which I could NOT Shift+F5 out of - I had to close MATLAB) that said something about an error loading the .fig file that was (probably) associated with a createfnc (or the like). I checked the GUI's .m file, and I thought all the renames had gone through.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Is there a way to force the GUI's .m file to update (i.e. force the changes on the .fig through to the .m)?

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get a message telling you that *"something about an error loading the .fig file that was (probably) associated with a createfnc (or the like)*??.

Comment: YES! Someone on the MATHWORKS question-board suggested either rebuilding the .m file through GUIDE, or going over the .m file with a magnifying glass to see if I can find the problem.